# Reuse logic in Python functions that involve Return

Tags: python

I have a long list of functions that all have the same initial part.

```
default_value = 123

def func_1(input):
  if apply_some_check(input):
    return default_value
  return do_something_1(input)
  
def func_2(input):
  if apply_some_check(input):
    return default_value
  return do_something_2(input)

def func_3(input):
  if apply_some_check(input):
    return default_value
  return do_something_3(input)

......
```

Is there any way to reuse the

```
  if apply_some_check(input):
    return default_value
```

part of the code, while keeping this list of functions (required by my code reviewer for readability)?

Comment: may be you can wrap that thing in decorator. andl you will have to call that decorator everywhere but it will be a one line in the beginning of other functions.

Comment: First of all, there is nothing inherently wrong about this. As long as the checks are short and make sense, it's okay to have them repeated. If you wanted to reduce the amount of duplication, you could either check the input at the place where these functions are called, assuming it's only one or very few places. Alternatively you could unify all those functions under one function, or under one class. But this really depends heavily on the nature of said functionality.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Well said. In my case, we want to keep the logic for each case (function) clear and self-contained. We don't want to actually unify them because there are a few exceptions. I think the decorator approach fits my need pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use decorators for this.

```py
def checked(f):
  def inner(inp):
    if apply_some_check(inp):
      return default_value
    return f(inp)
  return inner

# checked takes a function and returns a function, we can now use it as a function decorator
@checked
def some_func(inp):
  return do_something(inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use `partial` if it fits to your needs as follows:

```
from functools import partial

default_value = 123

def apply_some_check(a):
    return False

def func_template(do_something, a):
    if apply_some_check(a):
        return default_value
    return do_something(a)

def do_something_1(a):
    return "test1" == a

def do_something_2(a):
    return "test2" == a

def do_something_3(a):
    return "test3" == a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = "test2"
    funcs = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        funcs.append(partial(func_template, eval(f"do_something_{i}"), a))
    for f in funcs:
        print(f())
```

Result:

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this works, but it's pretty hard to follow at least to my level of python